# Permission denied (publickey). When creating a new branch

Tags: git

I have a git repo that I have worked on for weeks and everything is fine.

I want to add a **new branch**:

1.I created the branch named `feature`

2.Locally, I run `git fetch && git checkout feature`

This gives me:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

NB: When I work on the **master branch** of the same repo, everything is fine and I can `push` and `pull` with no problems.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was is that I created the branch from the website, not locally with commands.

When I run `git branch` locally, which supposed to give me the list of branches.

It only gave me the `master` branch.

So, I fixed it like this:

I deleted the branch from `delete-branch` button.

I recreated it locally using git:

```
    $ git branch <feature_branch> //create a new branch,

    $ git branch // to list them 

    $ git checkout <feature_branch> // work on new branch

    $ git add .     

    $ git commit -m "adding a change to the feature branch"

    $git push origin feature_branch
```

Comment: To me it's not clear if this is an answer or an addition. If it is an *answer* to your original question, please state something like "It's working for me using the following solution:" at the beginning. If it is an *addition* to your original question, please delete this answer and *edit* the original question!